# td colspan does not work while using jquery show/hide()

Tags: jquery

I have a table of content

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name </th>
    <th>Last Name </th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Deo</td>
    <td><a class="personal-checking-more-link">More</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td style="display:none" colspan="3">Description goes for 1st row</td></tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>Jaden</td>
    <td>Aidan</td>
    <td><a class="personal-checking-more-link">More</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td style="display:none" colspan="3">Description goes for 2nd row</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

When I click on **More** then 1st row Description will shown. it shows perfactly but colspan does not work.

here is my js code

```
personalChecking = function () {
        $('a.personal-checking-more-link').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle('slow');
        });

    }
$(document).ready(personalChecking);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sergio - How is this 4 year old question a duplicate of a day old question?

Answer (score 5):

This is the problem with 'display:block'

Please refer the below link
http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000376.html#.UUrg3FfCd1u

If you are hiding tr, then use 'display:table-row' instead of 'display:block' to display that tr,

If you are hiding td, then use 'display:table-cell' instead of 'display:block' to display that td

Comment: I don't know if you heard that before. But you're kind of a hero.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be in the style applied when showing an element.  It's setting the style to "display:block" which appears to be messing with colspan.  Here are some workarounds that I came up with, but they're not perfect.

This one has jerky annimation:

```
personalChecking = function () {
    $('a.personal-checking-more-link').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle('slow', function() {
            if($(this).css('display') == 'block')
            {
                $(this).css('display', '');
            }               
        });
    });
}
```

And this one has no annimation at all:

```
personalChecking = function () {
    $('a.personal-checking-more-link').click(function() {
        var nextRow = $(this).parent().parent().next();
        if(nextRow.css('display') == 'none')
        {
            nextRow.css('display','');
        }
        else
        {
            nextRow.css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your code:

```
$('a.personal-checking-more-link').click(function() {
    var descriptionTR = $(this).parent().parent().next();
    $(descriptionTR).toggle('slow').colSpan = 3;
});
```

http://www.nabble.com/IE7:-Setting-ColSpan-as-Attribute-td21252688s27240.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are toggling the TR, not the TD within it

```
$(this).parent().parent().next()
   1      2         3       4
```

- 1 is the A
- 2 is the TD the 1 is in
- 3 is the TR that 2 is in
- 4 is the TR below 3

But your display:none is on the TD within that.

So I would recommend:

```
$("td",$(this).parent().parent().next()).toggle('slow');
```

where the inner $ will get you the containing TR, and then you use that as context for the "td" selection.

Comment: I am getting a similar problem to the questioner, I am toggling a TR that has colspan'ed TDs. When I toggle the TR, I don't understand why it is not making the TDs visible.

Comment: I have just swithed from using slideToggle() to toggle() and now it works. It seems with slideToggle the TDs don't get displayed

Comment: In fact toggle("slow") breaks things as well. So basically anything animated causes the problem

Answer (score 2):

I found that the firefox 'problem' is because a  should have display:table-row. IE's glitch seems right since its glitches become interpreted as standard behavior.

So the best solution is use addClass("someClass") and removeClass("someClass") to make things hidden. (with a CSS rule: someClass {display:none;})

This has the drawback of not being animated. My solution could handle that. If not you can script in the css('display','table-row') somehow.

-Clint

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it without animation? i.e. just toggle()

I am getting the same problem, it seems the animated toggles aren't making the COLSPAN'ed TDs appear. I get all my row contents appearing in one of the non COLSPAN'ed columns. When I change it to a plain toggle() things work.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is using the callback

```
personalChecking = function () {
    $('a.personal-checking-more-link').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().next().show('slow', function() {           
            $(this).attr("colspan", "3");
        });
    });
}
```

this way FireFox and Chrome will know how to render the td exactaly

Answer (score 1):

Sorry It was my mistake. **style** tag should be place into **TR** not in **TD**

```
  <tr style="display:none"><td colspan="3">Description goes for 1st row</td></tr>
  <tr style="display:none"><td colspan="3">Description goes for 2nd row</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with jQuery and showing and hiding / sliding table rows in the past, in the end i had to get jQuery to wrap the selected td in a div and then show / hide that, not nice i know but on a tight deadline it worked.

Just something to keep in mind if you have similar issues with the animation.