# table is breaking -jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table, now on load i am hiding few last rows.Now on click of a span it will expand (last few rows)and collapse.I am using Slidetoggle(), and its working fine in IE, but the problem is its breaking in FF, first few rows are breaking in FF.how to fix this?any suggestion?
EDIT:

```
$("tr").slice(index).slideToggle('slow')//this works fine in IE but in FF, the first few rows became right-aligned, thus breaking the table layout, this can be fixed using dispaly:""..something like 
$("tr").slice(index).css("dispaly","")..
```

but I am using slidetoggle(). so facing the issue
EDIT:
HTML:

```
enter code here <div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            td1
        </td>
        <td>
            td11
        </td>
        <td>
           td111
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            td2
        </td>
        <td>
            td22
        </td>
        <td>
             td222
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            td3
        </td>
        <td>
            td33
        </td>
        <td>
            td333
        </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
            td3
        </td>
        <td>
            td33
        </td>
        <td>
            td333
        </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
            td3
        </td>
        <td>
            td33
        </td>
        <td>
            td333
        </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
            td3
        </td>
        <td>
            td33
        </td>
        <td>
            td333
        </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
            td3
        </td>
        <td>
            td33
        </td>
        <td>
            td333
        </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
            td3
        </td>
        <td>
            td33
        </td>
        <td>
            td333
        </td>
    </tr>   <tr>
        <td>
            td3
        </td>
        <td>
            td33
        </td>
        <td>
            td333
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Post some good, define breaking.

Comment: If you can provide the HTML you've been trying to work with, it will improve the odds of getting a specific answer.

Comment: Table based layout is sooooo ten years ago. http://davespicks.com/essays/notables.html

Comment: Table based layput is old..but this is tabular data(probably I was wrong with my tilte)

Comment: @outis: I have to agree with the question author here. There is nothing better than tables for tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the table HTML in addition to the javascript in the Question would further clarify, but the problem may be related to a [Firefox colspan quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269220/jquery-slidetoggle-doesnt-work-with-colspan-in-firefox).

So one work around is to dynamically wrap each innerHTML of each TD with a DIV as shown here:
[jQuery slideToggle doesn't work with colspan in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269220/jquery-slidetoggle-doesnt-work-with-colspan-in-firefox/1269236#1269236)

You could also experiment with re-setting the colspan:
[td colspan does not work while using jquery show/hide()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882372/td-colspan-does-not-work-while-using-jquery-show-hide/882419#882419)

Comment: Now that I refresh the page - boom: the table HTML. :)

Comment: Humm, I think thats the way.Thanks for the link :-)